# If $G$ is a group, is there any method which would enable us to know if G is congruent to A/B for some group A and normal subgroup B?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

If $G$ is a group, is there any method which would enable us to know if $G \cong A/B$ for some group $A$ and normal subgroup $B\,?$

If there is no general method for that, in which cases can we know if $G$ is isomorphic to some factor group or not?

And are there any assumptions on $G$ which make it easy to know something like that?

Remark : $B$ is Not the trivial subgroup.

Comment: You can always let $A=G\times B$. Is that what you mean, though?

Comment: Or you can always take $A=G$ and $B=\{1\}$.

Comment: @ChrisCulter ,  if $A= G \times B $ , What is the image of $g\in G$ ? Can you define an  isomorphism in general ?

Comment: @AlexYoucis , I mean Non-Trivial $B$ .

Comment: @MathsLover THen, just follow Chris's approach. The map is just cutting off the $B$-coordinate.

Comment: If you need it more explicit: consider the projection map $G\times B\to G$ (for any $B$) in light of the $1$st isomorphism theorem; you get $A/B\cong G$ where $A=G\times B$.

Comment: As the comments above (implicitly) point out, perhaps the question should fix both $G$ and $A$. Then I have to imagine this becomes a much more interesting question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The first isomorphism theorem:** if $\varphi: A\to G$ is a homomorphism of groups then $A/\ker\varphi \cong \mathrm{Im}(\varphi)$ hence if $\varphi$ is surjective then
$$A/\ker\varphi \cong G$$

Comment: Now you just need to show the existence of a surjective homomorphism whose domain is not $G$ itself!

Comment: OK, my issue was apparently handled by the preceding comments!

Answer (score 1):

No, it is undecidable whether a group $G$ is isomorphic to a factor group $A/B$. This problem is known as the [*isomorphism problem for groups*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_isomorphism_problem), and it is a classical result of Adian that this problem is undecidable in general.

On the other hand, if $G$ is finite and $A/B$ is known to be finite then this problem is soluble by brute force (I mean, you just see how all the elements multiply together and compare all possibilities between your two groups. This takes finite time.)

Comment: ,1- but the article in wikipedia says that the Isomorphism problem of GT says that two given finite group presentations , Can we make a decision if those two groups are isomorphic , How this problem is related to my question ?

Comment: @MathsLover Sorry, I should have explained that bit. They are related because presentations are simply encodings of groups of the form $A/B$ where $A$ is a free group.